# Low quality textures being baked to high poly mesh in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image, texture-baking, antialiasing

I want to bake a high poly spaceship to a low poly one in cycles. I do know the procedure(uv map the 2 objects, bake AO on the high poly mesh, select the high poly first, low poly later, then select 'Selected To Active' and press bake.) I have used a Ray distance of .02. But the problem is the low resolution texture I'm getting on the low poly mesh[image: Left:Low Poly, Right:High Poly]

Notice the jagged edges on the left ship?

The meshes were overlapping, I just seperated them after the bake to take a screenshot. Here is another image of the settings.
[image]

My question  is, how do I generate an even finer high res bake? Is there anything I'm missing out? Or any way to get Anti-aliasing done?(Not even sure if it applies here!)

Answer (score 2):

When you baking something, you have to create new Image in Blender. There is no way to change existing image resolution in Blender, so you should create new one, bigger, put it in appropriate Image Texture node and bake again into new image.

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is not low resolution, but bad (non-existent) anti-aliasing. I have struggled with this problem as well. It seems to be a bug in Cycles, as Blender Internal will handle a similar scenario very well (so in case of a low-res map, it will generate smooth output, despite low resolution).

If you need to use Cycles, I suppose you could double the res and then downsample the texture in an image-processing program. Otherwise stick to BI...

This is discussed here https://developer.blender.org/T43388 - apparently there is a fix you can apply if you feel like compiling Blender by yourself...

**Update:** sharing my Blender build for Win64 with the patch applied. It's based on 2.76rc1 if I remember right, so it can be a little behind the official release already in terms of bug fixes and such. Use at own risk, no warranty etc :) http://www.filedropper.com/blendercyclesbakingpatchbuildwin64

Comment: So I better bake it in blender internal. Thanks for the reply. As for the link posted above, it seems that there is some problem with lighting , like it produces artifacts and stuff. Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Since I wrote this, I have compiled my own Blender with the patch in the link. I'd say the baked textures are about 40% the quality of BI baked textures, which for my particular application was enough.

Comment: Oh and the artifacts problem is partially resolved. The devs insist this is not a full fix, but for practical purposes it's good enough.

Comment: Thanks for following me up! But I neither have the time nor the knowledge to compile my own blender. Anyplace where we can get these compiled builds?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I can share my build if you run Win64, although it's a few sub-revisions behind already relative to the official releases. I'll update my answer with a link if you want to give it a try.

Comment: Yup! Would definitely like to have a try!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think it has expired. I don't get anything to download.